# golang server: how to retrieve multiple files continuously

Tags: http, go, tcpserver

I have implemented a http server based on `gin` (golang web framework).

I post 2 pictures to server with `curl multipart/form-data`:

`curl -X POST -F upload0=@jpg -F upload1=@jpg -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" "http://server:port/path"`

Server code looks like this:

```
func extractImgs(c *gin.Context) {
    prefix := "prefix"
    for ix := 0; ix < 2; ix++ {
        file, _, err := c.Request.FormFile(prefix + strconv.Itoa(ix))
        if err != nil {
            // do sth.
            return
        }
        face_recognize_async(file)
    }
}
```

You know, face recognition is time-consuming, I hope the work-flow is:

```
get_1st_img -> recognize_face -> get_2nd_img -> recognize_face -> ...
```

I print `c.Request.FormFile()` execution time, it returns after retrieved **all 2 files**.

My questions:

1) how to retrieve these files continuously, just like traverse linked list;

2) Is http multipart a good choice, should I implement it with TCP/STCP?

Comment: What does you face_recognize_async look like? My guess is that it's async only in name, and actually blocks.

Comment: The entire http FORM POSt must be posted before its values can be parsed and operated on. You'll have to wait for all files to upload first.  Then, as @Alexey said, that async func may not actually be async.  Is it threadsafe? If so, fire off two Goroutines after the uploads are complete.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin face_recognize_async is actually async, I would send pictures to other GPU server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `FormFile` indexes the files from the posted form, it requires that the entire form already be parsed. From the `FormFile` docs:

> FormFile calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary.

If you want to stream the the multipart form one part at a time, use [`Request.MultipartReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.MultipartReader)